# Should I transfer strike water through a sparging device or more directly?

Tags: equipment, mash, sparge

I use a pump to move strike water from my HLT to the mash tun.  I've tried it with and without [this nozzle](https://www.northernbrewer.com/products/fermenters-favorites-fighter-jet-sparge) at the end of the hose.  The nozzle splatters water when my output valve is open more than about halfway; without it, I can open the valve wide open and mash in much faster.  The downside is, I have to add the nozzle back on before I vorlauf.

Are there any drawbacks to mashing in more slowly with the nozzle in place, or do you generally use your sparging device to add the strike water (and I just need a less messy one)?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you'll notice any difference in beer by throttling back. On my RIMS I get the strike water up to temp in the mash tun first, stop the pump completely, dough in, then restart the pump.  This has the benefit of getting all the equipment preheated.

Comment: Thanks.  I might experiment with a grain-into-water approach a few times before I make too many plumbing choices in my setup.